# Force Sequelize to do sub joins prior to on clause

Tags: sql, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have some sequelize Query along the lines of:

```
MainModel.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: SubModel1,
      required: true,
      include: [
        {
          model: SubModel2,
        }
      ],
      where: {
        '$s2.interested_key$': ###
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

this is producing bad SQL like:

```
select * from main_table mt
inner join sub_table_1 s1 on mt.table_sub_key1 = s1.id and s2.interested_key = ###
left outer join sub_table_2 s2 on s1.sub_table_key2 = s2.id
```

which fails as it is referencing an unknown column `s2.interested_key` before it is joined.

I need the query to look like:

```
select * from main_table mt
inner join (sub_table_1 s1 
    left outer join sub_table_2 s2 on s1.sub_table_key2 = s2.id
) on mt.table_sub_key1 = s1.id and s2.interested_key = ###
```

where it nests the joins before the on clause. anyone know how to force sequelize to do the query in this order?

Comment: how about putting `interested_key` inside one more nested at `SubModel2`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way to do this in Sequelize is to use raw queries.

See https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/